# Having problems with WaitForSeconds

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

So i'm trying to make a script for a "follower" which will start following the player on colliding with it. The problem is that i want the follower to wait for a given time before moving towards the player after every time the player will stop.

It works when the player collides with it, It moves toward the player after the given time but when the player stops and moves again the follower sticks with the player instead of waiting till the given time is over. Here's the script:

```
 void Update () {
     //running is a triggered true on colliding with player.
     if(running == true){
         StopCoroutine(Move());
         StartCoroutine(Move());
     }
 }
 IEnumerator Move(){
     yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.5f);
     Vector2 pos = transform.position;
     Vector2 playerpos = player.transform.position;
     playerpos.y = pos.y;
     transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(pos, playerpos, 1f * Time.deltaTime);
 }
```

Is there something that i'm doing wrong?

Also there is another issue, the follower moves faster then the given speed.

Function for player movement.

```
void Move(float horizontalinput){
    Vector3 pos = transform.position;
    pos.x += horizontalinput * maxSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = pos;
}
```

I'll really appreciate some help with it.

Comment: If I understand correctly then if the player stops moving, then the follower will keep following until it is at the position of the player. At this point the follower collides with the player again causing Move to run once more. But now the follower won't collide with the player anymore times because it has to first exit the players collider.
I think you should consider checking whether the player is moving, rather than checking whether the player collided with the follower.

Comment: I just added another condition in the if statement for checking if the player is moving or not and it did help with the timing but there is one more issue which is still there, something is causing the follower to move faster than the given speed which is "1f" and because of that the follower is sticking with the player while he is moving. I want the follower to  follow the player and when the player stops it should move into the player position.

Comment: Hmm.. that is odd.
How can you tell that it is moving faster than what you expect?
Are you sure nothing else is moving the follower?

Comment: The player is moving at the exact speed so when the player starts moving the follower waits for an amount of time and then starts to move toward the player with the same speed but instead of that the follower reaches the player while the player is moving and starts to stick with it until it stops. I actually tried using the Move() function i created for the player with the follower and delayed it using waitforseconds and the follower is still moving faster..

Comment: Hmm.. I think I need to see the code that moves the player if I am to figure out why.  Otherwise, couldn't you just either speed up the player or slowdown the follower?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

Create a variable called `_canMove` and set it to `false`. Then your `Update` would be:

```
private void Update()
{
    if(_canMove)
    {
        Move();
    }
}
```

Your `Move` method would be the same as it currently is, but minus the `WaitForSeconds` line. Then when the player stops run the following line which will prevent the `Update` method from calling the `Move` method:

```
_canMove = false
```

When the player starts to move again run the following:

```
StartCoroutine(ResetCanMove);
```

This will call `ResetCanMove` which will wait x-seconds before setting `_canMove` to `true` and in turn will cause `Update` to start calling `Move` again.

Here is the `ResetCanMove` method

```
private IEnumerator ResetCanMove()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    _canMove = true;
}
```

Comment: But there is still one issue left, when the player changes the direction without stopping, it starts to stick with the player again instead of waiting for that amount of time. Is there something i can do to avoid that?

Comment: You could track the player's current rotation and then when the rotation changes call the `StartRoutine` in the same way as when the player starts to move. I probably wouldn't do this for every rotation change because the rotation could be small. Instead, maybe check if the rotation changes by say 5 degrees, then call `StartCoroutine(ResetCanMove)`.

Answer (score 1):

`StopCoroutine(Move());` is stopping a new instance of the coroutine, not the one currently running.

either do:

```
StopCoroutine("Move");
StartCoroutine("Move");
```

or this:

```
private IEnumerator coroutine;

 void Update () {
     //running is a triggered true on colliding with player.
     if(running == true){
         StopCoroutine(coroutine);

         if(coroutine != null)
             coroutine = Move();

         StartCoroutine(coroutine);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are not using correctly StopCoroutine..

You can do something like this:

```
private Coroutine myCoroutine;

void Update () 
{
    //running is a triggered true on colliding with player.
    if(running == true)
    {
        if(myCoroutine != null)
        {
           StopCoroutine(myCoroutine); 
        } 

        myCoroutine = StartCoroutine(Move());
    }
}
```

Another option is use Start and Stop coroutines with the name of the element, but you will be using reflection, and that can affect the performance of your game.